# Basic JavaScript/JQuery Function Not Working for No Reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

My teammate and I have been tirelessly working at this seemingly impossible bug with js/jquery. We have a simple function called `feedback` in our .js file, but it is not working. See our replit link below:

https://replit.com/join/pryxsdvjtz-5pengoo

Please help.

Edit: Here's the function:

```
function feedback(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("this function ran");
  var text = $('#text');
  console.log(text);
}
```

I've reduced a lot of its functionality for debugging purposes but all I want it to do is print "this function ran" in the console. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, could you place the function in the question and explain what it's meant to do?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy of course. Just added! Also, feel free to check out the replit link for further detail.

Comment: @cocobeans, the code you posted is running. Not on Repl it though. But if I executed the code in a new tab, your feedback function is getting called.

Comment: @lokprakash so the problem is replit? how do I fix this? thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because I think, replit is not redirecting to create.html which you can verify from the url in the mini browser window. I feel this is how the replIt works. Whereas, if you tried in new tab you can see create.html in the url as a path. If the create.html is not loaded, then your script is also not loaded right. So, your function is not executed.

In the top right corner of the browser preview window in replit there is one option for opening the url in new tab. The code you posted works there. It is not working in the preview-browser-window. So there is nothing wrong with your code.